# Let n be an arbitrary odd natural number. Prove that $n^2≡1$ (mod4)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let n be an arbitrary odd natural number. Prove that $n^2≡1$ (mod4)

I know that this is true, but I'm not exactly sure how to write the proof for it. I found out then when you square any odd number, it will end in a 1,5,or 9, which I think is important. But then I can't say that whenever you subtract 1 from those to get a number ending in 0,4,or 8, that every number ending in 0,4, and 8 is divisible by 4 since for example, 38 is not, and others.

Comment: Well, it's not true.

Comment: I meant odd whoops, fixed it

Comment: Square $2k + 1$ and see what you get.

Comment: Even squaring $2k+1$ might be excessive, every odd number is either $1$ or $3$ mod $4$.

Comment: Well that's $4k^2+4k+1$

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n$ be odd. Then there exists an integer $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n = 2k+1$

$$n^2-1 = (2k+1)^2 - 1$$

$$= 4k^2+4k+1-1$$

$$=4k(k+1)$$

Then if $k$ is odd, then $k+1$ is even, and thus $k(k+1)$ is even, and if $k$ is even, then you know $k(k+1)$ is also even.

So there exists $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t $k(k+1) = m$. Thus we have $n^2-1 = 4k(k+1) = 4(m) = 4m$.

Hence we have $4|n^2 − 1$, that is,  $n^2≡1$ (mod$4$)

Comment: I don't think I can complete this sorry

Comment: i edited it @Cantwait428

Comment: Ok thanks yea now I see everything clearly

Comment: How do you know to use 2k+1?

Comment: @Cantwait428 You need to internalize definitions. Specifically, what it means to be odd or even, as well as congruence. The original version of this answer was already *plenty*.

Comment: ok thanks I see that now

Answer (score 2):

Even more:
if $n$ is odd then
$n^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 8
$.

Simple proof:

If $n$ is odd,
then $n = 2m+1$,
so that
$n^2
=(2m+1)^2
=4m^2+4m+1
=4m(m+1)+1
$.
$m(m+1)$ is even
since it is
the product of
two consecutive integers,
so $4m(m+1)$
is divisible by $8$.

Another simple proof:

$n^2-1
=(n-1)(n+1)
=2m(2m+2)
=4m(m+1)
$
is divisible by 8 as before.